# How to Establish a Connection to APNs for VoIP Call in iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to make a call to https://api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443 to work with flutter_callkit_incoming in iOS but it's return `Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response` in postman.

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNlLB.png)
[body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV5ib.png)

Comment: What is the message in the postman console?

Comment: [This](https://ibb.co/6WnLyZy) is the message

Comment: Have you tried the regular https port of 443 rather than 2197?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, same thing